# How to send a byte array to a serial device (C#)

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a serial device which sends me a string of ASCII Hex codes (e.g. 42 33). I then read these in and use them to bit rotate a checksum. Once they have been rotated I need to send them back to the serial device including some control bytes.

I feel my code may be overcomplicated and I am struggling to create a clean way to build a series of bytes to send back to the device.

```
// Calculate Checksum
private byte[] calcChecksum(string checksum)
{
    // Create a byte array from checksum string
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(checksum);

    // Create Hex Characters from ASCII codes of byte array positions 5, 6.
    string left = ((char)byteArray[5]).ToString();
    string right = ((char)byteArray[6]).ToString();

    // Convert Hex Characters to Integer values used for the shifting
    int numLeft = Convert.ToByte(left, 16);
    int numRight = Convert.ToByte(right, 16);

    // Dummy checksum values to shift
    string cs = ShiftLeft(0x5232, numLeft).ToString("x4");
    string kw = ShiftRight(0xab23, numRight).ToString("x4");

    string cskw = cs + kw;

    byte[] checksumBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cskw);

    return checksumBytes;
}

// Communicate with Serial device
private void bChecksum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read string from device. Need a better way to create this
    // instead of using a richtext box. Okay for now but suggestions
    // welcome.
    returnCode = tbOutput.Text;
    byte[] checksumBytes = calcChecksum(returnCode);

    // Bytes I need to send to the device. Here I need to insert all the
    // checksumBytes Array values between 0x1B and 0x03
    byte[] bytesToSend = { 0x04, 0x02, 0x31, 0x30, 0x1B, ...array bytes..., 0x03 };
    _serialPort.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
}
```

To clarify I need a way to insert the checksumBytes Array into the bytesToSend Array in between the 0x1B and 0x03 positions.

Additionally any code improvements would be most welcome.

Comment: What exactly is your question? _"Make this code more clean"_?

Comment: Does the write have to be in one go?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, I have edited the question to clarify what I am after.

Comment: @lc Yes, it needs to be in one go.

Comment: you want to insert checksumBytes to bytesToSend. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly then you could use the [Array.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to merge 3 arrays together;
            byte[] controlStart = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
            byte[] checksumBytes = { 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };
            byte[] controlEnd = { 0x07, 0x08, 0x09 };

```
        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[controlStart.Length + checksumBytes.Length + controlEnd.Length];

        controlStart.CopyTo(bytesToSend, 0);
        checksumBytes.CopyTo(bytesToSend, controlStart.Length);
        controlEnd.CopyTo(bytesToSend, controlStart.Length + checksumBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!